# RCCB - Residual Current Circuit Breakers (FID) are randomly blowing

Tags: circuit-breaker

We have a problem with FIDS (RCCB) randomly blowing, different cabinets, not connected at all. Trying to solve it for few months now with army of electricians... So far, we have measured 4000A occurring on the neutral sometimes, sometimes sinus wave is getting almost flat for a moment and then get's back to normal. Outside the building difference in the potential is 150V.

The building is for approx. 300 people, with metal facade, 4 different groundings. There is basically no exact pattern, could be from personal observation that when it is sunny outside things got much worser. Building is now 3 years old. Basically, there were no changes when problems started.

So far, electrical distribution company connected us to different source to rule out that option. Also tried to disconnect from electrical distribution power company at all and used diesel generator (but groundings were the same). Tried to disconnect department by department, disconnect different appliances like climate, lights,.. and blow-outs still occur randomly.

Any ideas? Can metal facade produce static electricity and we have bad groundings? Maybe even somewhere inside building connected ground and neutral?

Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: Sorry, what is "FIDS" abbreviation for?

Comment: Have you installed a history datalogger for all currents and voltages main supply when problem occur ?

Comment: RCCB - Residual Current Circuit Breaker (FID). 
Yes, main supply is fine. Electrical distribution company is measuring quality. They even switched us to different main supply. We have tried disconnecting the main supply and connecting the diesel generator...

Comment: Should this be migrated to home improvement?

Comment: Possibility of "local arcing" with "water" infiltration ?

Comment: "*4000 A on the neutral ...*" Your question is missing details of the supply voltage, number of phases, nominal current per phase and where the neutral to earth connection is. Your user profile says you are in Germany so I'm guessing 230 V, 3-phase, 50 Hz. Where are you measuring 150 V?

Comment: RCCB trip on VERY SMALL currents between phase and ground. Something like a spiders web in an unusued light socket, an outside lamp fitting now not used, anywhere that moisture or dust may get into a fitting. I've seen such things happen on a number of occasions.

Comment: A  fuse is NOT a circuit breaker.  Please fix title and tag.

Answer (score 1):

Static electricity won't generate enough power to do anything much.

If there is a lot of structural metalwork in the building, and it's heating up and cooling down during the day, then maybe it's a random intermittent short circuit between the wiring and the metalwork.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could be, as there were actually two earthquakes near with magnitude > 5 when those blackouts started. Well, not exactly after the earthquake but after 2-3 weeks, but yeah when weather was getting warmer.  Basically, part of the building is without electricity sometimes for 10 minutes, sometimes for few hours. Problems are much worser now when we have warmer weather.

Comment: Just not sure as all the wirings are shielded...

Comment: *a random intermittent short circuit between the wiring and the metalwork* would imply a fault in the same circuitry., which is not what is observed.